# How to make my local ELK stack accessible on the internet?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, port-forwarding, vmware

I wanted to make my ELK stack accessible from anywhere (the internet). i.e., If someone wants to access it from their machine. (they are not connected to my network in any way)

I have deployed ELK on Ubuntu (using a VMware workstation). My ELK stack is running on the following links in my Ubuntu browser.

`https://192.168.110.129:9201/`

`https://192.168.110.129:5601/`

(`192.168.110.129` = VM IP)
I have set the network.host: 0.0.0.0 (to make it listen to all IPs)

Using NAT method to port forward...
I have added the following in the Virtual Network editor.

[image: It is my NAT setting for both elastic search & kibana]

But it is not accessible outside my VM.

Can anyone please have a look and let me know what I am doing wrong? Actually, I am a beginner and don't know much, please answer in detail and clearly.

Comment: Can you open that link from a browser in a second VM on the same virtual network? If not, then check for firewall or binding issues. Can you access it from something on the same network as the host using the *Host* IP? like https://192.168.x.x:9201/

Comment: Actually, I do not have any second VM installed yet, but I disabled the firewall, its still not working.
Can you please let me know am i doing right? Even if its not working I am going in the right direction. I am new to this and did not know much.
I want to ask is it can run on any device on the internet using the method I am following. Or I have to change the ip to public ip? or it can accessible through private ip too?
btw thanks for replying. I am stuck on this problem from days.

Comment: Its not accessible from this link

https://192.168.1.1:9201/

This site can’t be reached192.168.1.1 refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
...
Can you please guide me where is the problem?

Comment: Is elk listening on port 9201 or 80? Your nat rule is pointing 192.168.1.1:9201 to 192.168.110.129:80, but it sounds like you might want the opposite, like host:80 to vm:9201